# Docker doesn't COPY files to created directories

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm kind of new to Docker, and I'm running into an issue I can't find a straightforward explanation for. I have a pretty simple Dockerfile that I'm building into an image, but when I deploy the image to Kubernetes as a pod, the results aren't what I expect.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN mkdir workspace
WORKDIR /workspace
COPY . /workspace
CMD ["ls"]
```

When I check the logs for the deployment, there are no files listed in the /workspace folder, even though the folder itself exists. However, if I change my `COPY`'s destination to a default linux folder like `/usr`, the files are there as I'd expect. My suspicion is that this has something to do with storage persistence, but since I'm copying the files into the folder when I build my image and the folder persists in the pod, I'm at a loss for why this happens. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you try removing RUN mkdir workspace and change the copy command to COPY . /workspace/

Comment: same results @Keaz

Comment: How do you run this image and view the empty directory? Do you include any options, particularly mounting volumes? What files are in the build context? Please show your commands and their output in the question.

Comment: can you run this image as docker run can check the logs? For me, it is working as you expected. I can see the files in the workspace folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would venture to guess that the `ubuntu:...` image doesn't have a WORKDIR set to /, and hence your copy command isn't working as expected.

Try changing the run command to be `RUN mkdir /workspace` and I think you'll see what you expected.

Hope this helps.